# APIGEE external OAuth 2.0 Authorization

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-api, apigee

I tried to set up an API proxy and do OAuth 2.0 autentification with a Google API token.
I got a Javascript for validating a google token and swiched  to true, setting the flowvariable oauth.externel.authorization.status=true if the token ist valid.
The result is always "errorcode":"oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken".

The question is, how to set the flow Variable right to skip the validation from client_id and secret against the internal key store?
 Or how can i set the tokenvalidation url to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= ?

edit:

```
<OAuthV2 async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="OAuth-v20-1">
<DisplayName>OAuth v2.0 1</DisplayName>
<FaultRules/>
<Properties/>
<Attributes/>
<ExternalAuthorization>true</ExternalAuthorization>

<Operation>VerifyAccessToken</Operation>
<SupportedGrantTypes/>
<GenerateResponse enabled="true"/>
<Tokens/></OAuthV2>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you are using to do the auth with? Not a lot to go on here.

Comment: I struggle with APIGEE API, if i try it without the APIGEE proxy everything works fine. Apigee policy are written in XML and its not much code but i´ll post it just a sek.

Comment: Are you trying to validate Googles access token using Apigee's Oauth policy (as opposed to Apigee minting a new token)?

Comment: Yes, sort of... my problem is, if i use a javascript Apigee continues to the page if the token is valid or not. Just throwing an exeption without catching it can interruped the process, but thats a ugly solution. 
So i found
 https://github.com/DinoChiesa/dpchiesa-elisp/blob/master/apigee.el 
line 667 where he explain how to trigger forwarding with a field Variable by setting ExternalAuthorization to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is, how to set the flow Variable right to skip the
>   validation from client_id and secret against the internal key store?

`<ExternalAuthorization>` is used to support external authorization and it is optional.
If it is enabled, a flow variable is expected with the name `oauth_external_authorization_status` set to either true or false based on the actual external authorization status.

If the `<ExternalAuthorization>` is set to true and `oauth_external_authorization_status` flow variable is set to true, the client_secret will not be validated (but the client_id is *still* expected in the request and *will be validated*).   You need to send in client_id as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is the default location to send in the client_id.

Taking a step back, you may wish to replace Google's token with Apigee's all together.  I recommend this approach because through Apigee-recognized tokens, you can leverage the rest of Apigee's objects/features.  These objects/features include Developers, Apps (including client_id/secret), custom attributes, and Analytics.

If you want to replace Apigee's access/refresh token, you can leverage Apigee's `<ExternalAccessToken>` and `<ExternalRefreshToken>` fields. When using these fields in generating the access token on Apigee, you can ensure Apigee recognizes the same access token Google produced.

I posted an answer on a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710888/apigee-oauth-authorization) that you may find helpful.

Comment: How does APIGEE expect the flow variable ? in the URL or is there another opportunity for handing a variable over ?

Comment: However you want to supply it: queryparam, hardcoded, header, etc.

Comment: also, you need to send in client_id as x-www-form-urlencoded.  This is the default location to send in the client_id